# How to solve NoSerializableException in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to Seriazlize an object `AnnotationList` which is an `ArrayList` of `AnnotationData` (also defined by myself and is serializable).

There always Errors:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone have ideas on how to solve this problem? Thanks.

```
public class AnnotationList extends ArrayList implements ListModel, Serializable {

    protected Object source;
    ArrayList listeners = new ArrayList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because something in the object graph that you are attempting to serialize is.... not serializable... So either make sure all objects in the graph are serializable (including all fields in your own classes), or mark the non-serializable fields as `transient`. Just making `AnnotationData` serializable is not enough if it in turn have fields that are not `Serializable`.